# Microsoft Onenote alternative with support for my stylus

Tags: software-recommendation

I know how many questions about onenote alternatives and I read through them but didn't find something fitting for me.

So what am I looking for?

- Support for my Stylus / hand written notes
- Adding files/pictures to the notes
- Some managing system to organize the notes / somewhat like OneNote

Comment: Henny, it is better if you specify your Stylus model, this is what makes your question apart from previous enquiries on Onenote.

Comment: Also, have you tried Office Web Apps? Is it missing support for some of these features?

Comment: The web app doesn't support any handwriting/drawing support

Comment: And my Stylus seems to me to be some special Sony model. As far as I know it does not run with the wacom driver. As of right now I can use it barely as mouse without right mouse button although it has got 2 buttons to it...

Comment: Ok Henny, your issue has two parts, first the software and then the hardware. As for the software, [Xournal](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xournal/) is probably the closest to your requirements, but does not fulfil everything. However, in order to use a programme like Xournal the way you wish, you need to get the Stylus working - and here I can not help much, apart from noting that this is an issue related to the kernel, not to software *per se*. My advise is to first focus on the Stylus and later on trying with different software options.

Answer (score 1):

There is, but you will need two programs. What I found very useful from OneNote is the ability to upload powerpoints, PDFs, docs, images, etc and type text on them directly, and use my **stylus (touch pen)** to write and draw diagrams directly on the files. I also liked the organization and search function of OneNote. To have these functions on Ubuntu, install Xournal if you want to use a touch pen (or point cursor) to draw/write on your files (export your powerpoint as PDF before opening with Xournal), then export your Xournal file as PDF, and install Mendeley to organize all your PDFs. Unlike OneNote, in Mendeley, you can direct select text, copy text, and click on links directly from the PDF files in Mendely. If you simply want to take notes and organize them, install EverPad. With Mendely, you can also search text in all of your files. You can sync Mendeley to all other devices and open them online after you create a free online account.